# C++ Image interpolation with Bicubic method

Tags: c++, image-processing, bicubic

I am just trying to smoothing the image by BiCubic interpolation. I got some code which is used to interpolate the RGB image. I have changed the code to work for Grayscale image. But in result i only got fully black image. Considered input and output image size are same. The code is pasted below. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
 inline Uint16 saturate(float x, unsigned max_pixel)
{
    return x > max_pixel ? max_pixel
        : x < 0.0f ? 0
        : Uint16(x);
}

inline float get_subpixel(const Uint16* in, std::size_t dest_width, std::size_t dest_height, unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    if (x < dest_width && y < dest_height)
        return in[(y * dest_width) + x];

    return 0;
}


void interpolate(unsigned dest_width, unsigned dest_height, unsigned bits_allocated, const Uint16* src, Uint16** dest)
{
    const double tx = 1;
    const double ty = 1;
    float C[5] = { 0 };
    unsigned max_bit = pow(2, bits_allocated);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < dest_height; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < dest_width; ++j)
        {
            const float x = float(tx * j);
            const float y = float(ty * i);
            const float dx = tx * j - x, dx2 = dx * dx, dx3 = dx2 * dx;
            const float dy = ty * i - y, dy2 = dy * dy, dy3 = dy2 * dy;


            for (int jj = 0; jj < 4; ++jj)
            {
                const int idx = y - 1 + jj;
                float a0 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x, idx);
                float d0 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x - 1, idx) - a0;
                float d2 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x + 1, idx) - a0;
                float d3 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x + 2, idx) - a0;
                float a1 = -(1.0f / 3.0f) * d0 + d2 - (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
                float a2 = 0.5f  * d0 + 0.5f *  d2;
                float a3 = -(1.0f / 6.0f) * d0 - 0.5f * d2 + (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
                C[jj] = a0 + a1 * dx + a2 * dx2 + a3 * dx3;

                d0 = C[0] - C[1];
                d2 = C[2] - C[1];
                d3 = C[3] - C[1];
                a0 = C[1];
                a1 = -(1.0f / 3.0f) * d0 + d2 - (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
                a2 = 0.5f  * d0 + 0.5f  * d2;
                a3 = -(1.0f / 6.0f) * d0 - 0.5f * d2 + (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
                (*dest)[i * dest_width + j] = saturate(a0 + a1 * dy + a2 * dy2 + a3 * dy3, max_bit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any out-of-bound acesses during get_subpixel-calls? It will return 0 ( black ) when you are out of bound. A debugger could help you here. Just my first idea.

Comment: Thank for your reply...there are some out of bound access but not for all calls

Comment: i checked the result pixel values. they are mostly below value 100.

Comment: just a side note: you cannot improve image quality by interpolation. to your problem: I haven't read through all your code but I see alot of float and uint16 stuff. Is it possible that you have a 8bit input and something bigger as output? if you have values below 100 in a 16bit image you see black. just a quick guess..

Comment: thanks for your reply. input also 16 bit image.

Comment: I see a lot of pixel offset calculation looking like `[y * height + x]`.  I'm not familiar with this code, but normally one multiplies `y` by a stride, or the width in pixels, then adds x.  This is because each `y` unit represents a whole row of pixels, and a row normally contains `width` pixels.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? What are values before (*dest) filling? Is `saturate` works good for this eclectic type mixture?

Comment: thank you @Christopher Oicles. thanks for the reply. you are right. its should be [y * width + x]. Actually i changed that in my source code. still problem exist

Answer (score 1):

How can you have this? The c's havent been computed until the jj loop ends the brace should be above the d's - I'm not considering  if the method is correct otherwise.

```
for (int jj = 0; jj < 4; ++jj)
        {
            const int idx = y - 1 + jj;
            float a0 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x, idx);
            float d0 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x - 1, idx) - a0;
            float d2 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x + 1, idx) - a0;
            float d3 = get_subpixel(src, dest_width, dest_height, x + 2, idx) - a0;
            float a1 = -(1.0f / 3.0f) * d0 + d2 - (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
            float a2 = 0.5f  * d0 + 0.5f *  d2;
            float a3 = -(1.0f / 6.0f) * d0 - 0.5f * d2 + (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
            C[jj] = a0 + a1 * dx + a2 * dx2 + a3 * dx3;

        // } // end jj

            d0 = C[0] - C[1];
            d2 = C[2] - C[1];
            d3 = C[3] - C[1];
            a0 = C[1];
            a1 = -(1.0f / 3.0f) * d0 + d2 - (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
            a2 = 0.5f  * d0 + 0.5f  * d2;
            a3 = -(1.0f / 6.0f) * d0 - 0.5f * d2 + (1.0f / 6.0f) * d3;
            (*dest)[i * dest_height + j] = saturate(a0 + a1 * dy + a2 * dy2 + a3 * dy3, max_bit);
        } // end jj move his above
    }
}
```

Comment: you gave me a valid point. thank you. but answering your question, the loop end bracket wont affect, because C array is already intialized with 0's so no out of index problem occur. Also same index on (*dest) will be assigned 4 time until the jj loop ends. so last value which we need will be assigned in that index at last iteration of the jj loop. but logically what i did was not correct. but technically its working:)

Comment: i dont know why this computation should be wasted - can you point to the original code that you got?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share great link
[cubic splines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFFPbBe7aAs)